# Guidelines on forking an unmaintained npm package?

Tags: npm

tl;dr: Are there any community guidelines on what to do if you need to patch an unmaintained npm package?

More details:

We needed to fork a working, but unmaintained (4 years without a PR, npm based NodeJS package, since its dependencies were outdated and causing vulnerability warnings.

We now want to make that fork available. Our initial idea was simply to slap '2' as name extension and republish, such as 'somepackage2', though this might just end up polluting the npm library, so we are looking to see if there is a way to simply replace the current version?

We are trying to get hold of the current author, but in the case we are unable to contact that person, are there any community guidelines on what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some more hunting and this page seems to outline what to do: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/disputes.html

The tl;dr sections states:

> 1. Get the author email with npm owner ls
> 2. Email the author, CC support@npmjs.com
> 3. After a few weeks, if there’s no resolution, we’ll sort it out. Don’t squat on package names.
>
> Publish code or move out of the way.

So essentially contact them, and if the original author doesn't respond or help out, then there is potential to replace the package with the fork. Dead projects can't hold on to a name forever.